# Copy/paste from Word to Excel

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I have a macro that extracts text from a Word document and pastes it into an Excel file. The macro searches for specific names defined in an array and copies the corresponding text to the designated Excel file.

Here's the current code for the macro:

```
Option Explicit

Private vList() As Variant
Private strWorkbook As String
Private strSheet As String
Sub ExtractText()

strWorkbook = BrowseForFile("Select Workbook", True)
If Not strWorkbook = vbNullString Then

strSheet = "URL"

On Error Resume Next
    vList = Array("MS MARY LOK", "MS MARY MA", "MS MARY CHAN")
    Dim oDoc As Document
    Dim oRng As Range
    Dim i As Long

    Set oDoc = ActiveDocument
    Set oRng = oDoc.Range
    With oRng.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        .Font.BOLD = True
        Do While .Execute()
            For i = 0 To UBound(vList)
                If oRng.Text = CStr(vList(i)) Then
                     WriteToWorksheet strWorkbook, strSheet, oRng.Text
                    Exit For
                 End If
            Next i
        Loop
    End With
lbl_Exit:
    Exit Sub
    End If
    
End Sub
Private Function BrowseForFile(Optional strTitle As String, Optional bExcel As Boolean) As String
Dim fDialog As FileDialog
    On Error GoTo err_Handler
    Set fDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    With fDialog
        .Title = strTitle
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Filters.Clear
        If bExcel Then
            .Filters.add "Excel workbooks", "*.xls,*.xlsx,*.xlsm"
        Else
            .Filters.add "Word documents", "*.doc,*.docx,*.docm"
        End If
        .InitialView = msoFileDialogViewList
        If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo err_Handler:
        BrowseForFile = fDialog.SelectedItems.Item(1)
    End With
lbl_Exit:
    Exit Function
err_Handler:
    BrowseForFile = vbNullString
    Resume lbl_Exit
End Function
Private Function WriteToWorksheet(strWorkbook As String, _
                                  strRange As String, _
                                  strValues As String)
Dim ConnectionString As String
Dim strSQL As String
Dim CN As Object
    ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
                       "Data Source=" & strWorkbook & ";" & _
                       "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;"";"
    strSQL = "INSERT INTO [" & strRange & "$] VALUES('" & strValues & "')"
    Set CN = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Call CN.Open(ConnectionString)
    Call CN.Execute(strSQL, , 1 Or 128)
    CN.Close
    Set CN = Nothing
lbl_Exit:
    Exit Function
End Function
```

However, I have two issues with the current code:

1. I want to include more than 200 names in the array, but the current code only allows me to define up to less than 50 names. Can anyone suggest how to modify the code to handle more than 200 names?
2. The macro sometimes pastes the text to the wrong cell. I want it to paste at cell A2, but it sometimes pastes to B15, sometimes to B3. Can anyone help me understand which code determines the cell where the macro pastes the text?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: This is not a recommendation, only to widen my knowledge. Why do y use this Database Connection method approach, when Office has direct and fast Automation for Excel and Word?

Comment: @Blackcat Thank you for your reply. Do you have any suggestions on extracting specific  text from a Word document and pastes it into an designated Excel file? I just want to use VBA to make such process more convenient as I need this to automatically copy more than 200 names from Word to Excel, then use another macro to automatically add hpyerlinks to those names in Word Document. That's why I need such Database Connection method approach.

Comment: As far as I understand, the output of `oRng.Text` is inserted to excel. I want to ask you this. What is the output format? Is it plain text that is inserted in a single cell? Is it some kind of list that is pasted in an entire column?

Comment: @mits Thank you for your reply. It is plain text that is inserted in a single cell.

Answer (score 1):

This is a sample code, you have to adapt to the exact target cells.

Place it in a Module of Excel.

Open the Word document and Excel sheet where the data are.

The code will place from cell A24 and down the found bold names.

```
Sub ExcelWord()
const columnvalue=1
vList = Array("MS MARY LOK", "MS MARY MA", "MS MARY CHAN")
Set oApp = GetObject(, "word.application")
Set oDoc = oApp.ActiveDocument
Set oRng = oDoc.Range
    With oRng.find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        .Font.Bold = True
        .MatchCase = False
        Do While .Execute()
            For i = 0 To UBound(vList)
                If UCase(oRng.text) = vList(i) Then
                     ActiveSheet.Cells(24 + i, columnvalue) = oRng.text
                    Exit For
                 End If
            Next i
        Loop
    End With
End Sub
```

If the array is too short (depends on Excel version) use multiple arrays and add another for ... next loop to the compare loop.

Comment: Thank you for your help. However, it doesn't copy words to the designated cell.

Comment: Did you get error message? If not insert this code before line `Activesheet.Cells .....`
Debug.Print oRng.Text, vList(i). Check the immediate window of the result. There are the compared items. If no errors were generated, mostly probably there is no matching of words. (The code is tested) @tcl75

Comment: Thank you for your reply. There is no error message since it crashed after it just runs. There are matching of words but it cannot identify and copy and paste them from Word to Excel.

Comment: Under Sub ExcelWord() insert this line `Application.DisplayAlerts = True`. This enables error messages to display. In the Immediate Window are there any prints? Delete all lines in the window before starts the macro. If it crashes there is a problem with Excel.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried to run your macro on a Word Document with just 1 page and it successfully copied and paste to Cell A24. However, it cannot be used on a Word Document with more than 150 pages. And I still cannot find the error messages since it crashed when ran for more than 150 pages.

Comment: Be sure that this is not the problem of the above code. Page count is irrelevant. I feel that this is not the subject of your original question. Pls. ask it in a new one.

Comment: This is not the problem of the code. I will ask a new one. Many thanks for your help!